# Generate SAML response/assertion in java

Tags: java, saml, assertion

I am working on idp-initated authentication. I want to generate SAML response to be sent to SalesForce. I have necessary values to be set in the response from metadata. Please tell me openSAML classes to use in order to generate response/assertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the main classes that will be used.

Assertion
Signature
SubjectConfirmationData
NameID
Subject
Conditions
Audience
AuthnContextClassRef
AuthnStatement

see this for openSAML libraries [link](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home/)

Comment: How to get SAMLAssertion String from the SAMLResponse? I've converted it using Base64, but getting with {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid."}, no specific error message /wso2is-5.0.0/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log file, Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create SAML Assertions and want some convenience methods that will help you deal with the OpenSAML library, you can take a look at WSS4J's SAML2ComponentBuilder.  This is used extensively in Apache CXF and other Java service stacks.

Creating an assertion is as easy as:

```
        //Create assertion
    Assertion assertion = SAML2ComponentBuilder.createAssertion();

    //create issuer
    Issuer issuer = SAML2ComponentBuilder.createIssuer(issuerString);
    assertion.setIssuer(issuer);
```

You can obviously set all the values described above and there is an 'AssertionWrapper' provided that assists in digitally signing the assertion:

assertionWrapper.signAssertion( alias, password, signatureCrypto, false, defaultCanonicalizationAlgorithm, defaultRSASignatureAlgorithm);

It is worth looking into if you are having difficultly dealing directly with the OpenSAML library.

Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: How to get SAMLAssertion String from the SAMLResponse? I've converted it using Base64, but getting with {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid."}, no specific error message /wso2is-5.0.0/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log file, Please help me out